# Resettable persistence sensor

Tags: sensor

I need somehow to manage pallet movement in one of factory sections. Since my controller can't work with interruption from I/O I need to get I/O reading cycle. But for this reason I need my persistence sensor generate high level when pallet moves in and still be in such position till I reset it to low level by using controllers output. Sensor should stay in high level even if palette move out.

- Is there any classification of such sensors?
- How to search for them online?

Comment: What is a persistence sensor? Do you mean a position sensor? Anyway, I think you just want some sort of SR latch in combination with a regular sensor.

Comment: persistence = photosensor. Activates, when object moves in

Comment: Sounds like the perfect job for an SR latch then. They cost pennies on digikey and you can find one that runs on the same voltage as your photosensor.